# jQuery ui dialog wont work second time

Tags: jquery

Hi I have an button and onClick i pop up a jQuery ui Dialog box with some form elements in it. the first time i click everything works perfectly but second time i click the box appears but my form elements are gone and its just an empty dialog box. Any ideas whats going wrong? The code im using is:

```
var $dialog = $('<div id="saveDialog"></div>')
    .html('Please choose the folder you wish to save the file in:')
    .dialog(
    {
        autoOpen: false,
        modal: true,
        buttons: {Ok: function()
            {
                $( this ).dialog( "close" );
            }},
        show: "blind",
        hide: "explode",
        resizable: true,
        minWidth: 500,
        maxWidth: 800,
        height: 400,
        open: function()
        {
            var phpArray = <?php echo json_encode($directories); ?>;
            $.each(phpArray, function (i, elem) 
            {
                   $('#saveDialog').append('<br> <img src="/app/webroot/css/jqueryFileTree/images/directory.png"/><a id="'+elem+'">'+elem+'</a>');

            });
         }

$dialog.dialog('open');
    return false;
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: On close, try removing the dialog from the dom.

Comment: By removing it from the dom do you mean have this var $dialog = $('<div id="saveDialog"></div>')
    .html('Please choose the folder you wish to save the file in:'); seperate from the .dialog part?

Comment: No sorry, you can specify a close function i.e.  
close: function() { $(this).remove() }

Comment: The first comment was correct i had it outside the Dom and not in document.ready. Cheers man.

Comment: Ha, glad it's sorted. (p.s please note that without the removal from the dom on close the modal window still exists in the dom just hidden, so if you click the button again it may be populated with the values from last time)

Comment: Thanks @Magrangs.. I too faced the same issue and now got resolved it with the help of your comment..